# JQUERY - Enabling a Click Event within an Area that already has a click event attached

Tags: jquery

[image]

The above image is a `<td>`.
The language is Japanese and if you click an where in the green area it will show language options. 
The words English allows someone who does understand Japanese to just go to Japanese.

The `<td>` and the word english have click events.
if you click english is goes to the english version but before it changes you see the other `<td>` click event fire.

Is there a way to supress the second click event once the first has happened.

code:

```
 <td id="languages">
    <a id="navLanguages" class="navJoinLinks">
    <?php echo $siteLanguages->languages;?>
    <?php if($_SESSION['language'] != 'english') {echo '<span id="defaultEnglish">English</span>';}?>
 </a></td>
```

and then the `<td>` and `<span>` have the click events tied to them.

thx

Comment: Just make `english` container `position: absolute` in css and make it fill the whole right area, then adjust till you get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `stopPropagation` in the `defaultEnglish` clickhandler:

```
$('#defaultEnglish').click(function(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();

    /* ...then do whatever... */
});
```

Read more about it here: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

> Description: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree,
>   preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Normally, when you click on an item, it starts by sending a click event directly to that item. Then to that item's parent. Etc, all the way up the tree. This is called "event bubbling". It's not just clicks, most events bubble like that. `stopPropagation` stops the bubbling at whatever element the handler is attached to.

Also, since `#navLanguages` is an an anchor tag, it has a default action (redirect the page to the `href` value). Since you are manually handling clicks in this area, you probably don't want to allow that either. To do that, you'd use [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) like this:

```
$('#navLanguages').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    /* ...then do whatever... */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop event propagation, as clicking on the inner element is causing the outer elements to trigger their events as well:

```
$('#english, #japanese').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```